# (Help) Error in function 'WinMain' in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi

I was trying coding a simple Win32 GUI Application using Eclipse CDT (Eclipse used in C++) but it throws an error which says:

> conflicting declaration of C function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, int, LPSTR, int)

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX cWindow;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Msg;

    cWindow.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    cWindow.lpszClassName = "cls";
    cWindow.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    cWindow.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    cWindow.hInstance = hInstance;
    cWindow.style = CS_OWNDC;
    cWindow.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    cWindow.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    cWindow.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    cWindow.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)3;
    cWindow.cbClsExtra = 0;
    cWindow.cbWndExtra = 0;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&cWindow))
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error registring window class!", "Fatal error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "cls", "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          640, 640, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    return 0;
}
```

It is on C++ language, and I'm using MinGW compiler

Comment: I can't see anything specific wrong but a simple fix is to use a standard `int main()` instead. With that change, replace `hInstance` with `GetModuleHandle( 0 )`.

Comment: **Unable to reproduce**, it compiles fine with MinGW g++ 4.9.1

Comment: Ok. I have just opened Eclipse and NOW, it doesn't show any kind of error...

Comment: Regarding the error message box thing, first you will want to use `MB_SETFOREGROUND` to make the box guaranteed be visible when the program's run as a console program from an existing console, and secondly, you want to exit the program at this point, and not go on trying to create a window etc. For more general "present an error box" you would also want to empty the message queue first. It's slightly tricky.

Comment: Also, regarding the message loop, implicit conversion to boolean will convert the negative value denoting an error, to `true`. A good C++ solution to is code up an exception based wrapper of `GetMessage`.

Comment: Regarding the declaration `WNDCLASSEX cWindow;`, you would do well to *zero-initialize* that, i.e. `WNDCLASSEX cWindow = {};`.

Comment: Finally, modern Windows programming is largely Unicode-based, using `wchar_t` type instead of `char`, and UTF-16 encoding. E.g.., `CommandLineToArgvW` is not available as `char`-based ANSI-encoding version. So, define `UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>`, and use wide string literals such as `L"Hello"`.

Comment: Yes, it was a quickly code to check Eclipse ID. I know I should write (GetMessage(...) > 0) :D